# When does PST display contexts from left to right and right to left?

Tags: r, pst, traminer

Does the `PST` package always display contexts from right to left?

In the `query()` function we use a string to represent a context. If I'm assuming that the context is specified from right to left (as it seems to be in the `print()` and `cmine()` functions), and I'm interested in the sequence `A->B->C`, then should I query for:

```
query(S1.p1, "C-B-A")
```

?

Further, in the `predict()` function, we use `seqdef()` to define sequences to predict for. Does that mean I should specify them from left to right, as TraMineR usually does?

```
x <- seqdef("A-B-C)
predict(S1.p1, x)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a probabilistic suffix tree (PST), a branch defines a suffix from right to left when we start reading it from the root. At the first level you have the last element of the suffix, at level 2 you have the element preceding the last element, etc. The printed tree is displayed with the root on the left side and is expanded from left to right. Nevertheless, the suffixes displayed in a node of the print outcome should be read naturally from left to right. E.g, a node `a-b-c` means a suffix with `c` at the end. Such a node is obtained from the node `b-c` by adding `a` on the left.

The same holds for the outcome of `cmine`. For each found context, e.g. `a-b-c`, `cmine` gives the probability to get each of the possible state immediately after the context, i.e., after `c` in the example.

In summary, sequences and contexts are always displayed from left to right, even though contexts are built from right to left.

So, if you want query for the sequence  `A->B->C`, just use `query(S1.p1, "A-B-C")`. Likewise, to predict a specific sequence with `predict`, define the sequence naturally from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

The sequences should be read from left to right. The following code provides validation of this:

```
library(PST)
data.seq <- seqdef("A-B-C-D-E-F")
S1.test <- pstree(data.seq, ymin = 0.001, lik = FALSE, with.missing = FALSE)
print(S1.test)

--(e)-[ p=(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2) - n=6 ]
  `--(A)-[ p=(0.001,0.995,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001) - n=1 ]--| 
  `--(B)-[ p=(0.001,0.001,0.995,0.001,0.001,0.001) - n=1 ]
     `--(A-B)-[ p=(0.001,0.001,0.995,0.001,0.001,0.001) - n=1 ]--| 
  `--(C)-[ p=(0.001,0.001,0.001,0.995,0.001,0.001) - n=1 ]
     `--(B-C)-[ p=(0.001,0.001,0.001,0.995,0.001,0.001) - n=1 ]
        `--(A-B-C)-[ p=(0.001,0.001,0.001,0.995,0.001,0.001) - n=1 ]--| 
  `--(D)-[ p=(0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.995,0.001) - n=1 ]
     `--(C-D)-[ p=(0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.995,0.001) - n=1 ]
        `--(B-C-D)-[ p=(0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.995,0.001) - n=1 ]
           `--(A-B-C-D)-[ p=(0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.995,0.001) - n=1 ]--| 
  `--(E)-[ p=(0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.995) - n=1 ]
     `--(D-E)-[ p=(0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.995) - n=1 ]
        `--(C-D-E)-[ p=(0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.995) - n=1 ]
           `--(B-C-D-E)-[ p=(0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.995) - n=1 ]
              `--(A-B-C-D-E)-[ p=(0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.995) - n=1 ]--|


plot(S1.test)
```

[image: Validation of bottom-to-top reading of plotted tree]

It also shows that the plotted tree should be read from bottom to the top.